# Cache Hit Rate decrease postgres

Tags: postgresql, hashing

On one of our servers, I found a problem: for the last three months, this indicator has been steadily decreasing, already from 95% to 89%. With what it can be connected? How to understand which requests do not fall into the hash?

Comment: Why do you care?  At what cache hit rate will your system become unusable?

Comment: @jjanes the monitoring system began to display a warning. It is clear that this is not critical, but still I would like to understand the reasons.